# Understanding bitwise left shift on signed types in C++14

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, language-lawyer, c++14, bit-shift

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators),

> For signed `a`, the value of `a << b` is `a * 2^b` if it is
>   representable [in the unsigned version of the (since C++14)] return
>   type [(which is then converted to signed: this makes it legal to
>   create `INT_MIN` as `1 << 31`) (since C++14)], otherwise the behavior
>   is undefined.

I can't quite understand this specification. What does it mean exactly by *if it is representable in the unsigned version of the return type*? Does it apply only to the case when the signed value is non-negative? Are `INT_MIN << 1` and `-1 << 31` well-defined?

Comment: The most significant bit (in the value representation) is a sign bit in all three representations of signed integers allowed by the standard. However, the binary pattern 10000...000 is not `INT_MIN` with sign-and-magnitude representation. Also, `int` is not necessarily 32-bit.

Comment: "if it is representable in the unsigned version of the return type" just means to no 1-bit is shifted out of the value.

Comment: It looks like that part of cppreference could do with a bit of cleaning.

Comment: `INT_MIN << 1` and `-1 << 31` are both undefined behaviour still

Comment: Well, a negative number is certainly not representable in an unsigned type....

Comment: That's not a specification. It's a word salad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go to source, the C++14 Standard, this is what we find (with the part about unsigned types highlighted):

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2`<sup>`E2`</sup> , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, **if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1 × 2`<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value**; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

For a platform in which [`std::numeric_limits<int>::digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) is 31, it is legal to perform `1 << 31`. The resulting value in `unsigned int` will be `0x80000000` or `2147483648`. However, that number is beyond the valid range of value of `int` for such a platform. However, that bit pattern, when treated as a two's complement representation `int` is equal to `-2147483648`, which is the same as `INT_MIN` for such a platform.

If you use

```
int a = 2 << 31;
```

you invoke undefined behavior since `2 * 2`<sup>`31`</sup> is not representable as an `unsigned int` in that platform.

> Are INT_MIN << 1 and -1 << 31 well-defined?

No, they are not. Bitwise left shifting negative numbers is undefined behavior. Notice the use of **non-negative value** in the above highlighted text.

Comment: `x << 32` is undefined behavior anyway, even for unsigned integer value `x`, for shifting a number of bits greater or equal to that of `x` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lingxi, I meant to use `2 << 31`.

Comment: @Lingxi - `x << 32` is well-defined if `x` has type `unsigned` and the compiler defines `int` as a type that has more than 32 bits. That sounds a bit hyper-technical, but when you're dealing with bits you **have to** think about the actual sizes that are involved.

Comment: As we are being pedantic here, `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` isn't right either, because you may have padding bits.

Comment: @T.C., how could I improve that line?

Comment: Use `numeric_limits`.

Comment: @T.C., how can I get `32` from `numeric_limits` and `int`?

Comment: `numeric_limits<int>::digits + 1`.